Relation between Earth's and Sun's magnetic axis relative to their paths of travel and relative to each other?
Pretext
As non-educated citizen with no academic background, and based on watched PBS Space Time's latest video I've got curious, what's the relation between Earth's and Sun's magnetic axis relative to their paths of travel and relative to each other.
By non-ScarJo-AI-bot I was provided with some sophisticated python code from another galaxy and this image:

that I (have no idea if really true) find not convincing at all. Unfortunately, all my further queries were surprisingly denied and flagged with "can’t do more advanced data analysis right now".
Assumptions
As of my understanding, Sun's poles switch places aprox. every 11 years, but position of this NS axis remains close to or same
We take a small non-essential region of Sun's orbit and plot the travel direction on x axis.
And also for simplicity, we treat Earth's orbit as spherical instead of helical.
Question
What is the true position of these two NS magnetic axis relative to each other?
subquestions (related to main question for better understanding of what's the ask - not to be mistaken as "asking multiple questions" and due to this, resulting in question closure)

are they positionaly locked to each other
are they positionaly locked to their respective paths
does Sun's axis spin related to Sun's path
is the image close to truth
does Earth's axis spin, is it fixed, does it revolve around Sun's axis


hope it's clear enough

Why do you think there has to be any relation? Earths magnetic field is decided by complex internal geodynamics.

@Triatticus now I'm not sure if "position" would be a better word to use instead of "relation" as it could indicate I'm asking about relationship b/n them. in other words I'm just interested in position of those vectors in 3D space and if/how they move

and of course it got closed due to no reason...

@xray0 It is not clear what you're asking. The location and movement of earth's magnetic pole is well-documented. Since the magnetic axis is not exactly parallel to the rotation axis, the pole will rotate with the Earth. The orientation of Earth's rotation axis is also well-documented. See https://astropedia.astrogeology.usgs.gov/download/Docs/WGCCRE/WGCCRE2015reprint.pdf. It's not difficult to work out the vectors from these data.

Also it is completely unclear why you asked an AI for this. AI chatbots cannot provide guaranteed factually correct answers.

The image is far from the truth. For example, the Earth's North/South poles are somewhere near perpendicular to the plane of the orbit.

@VincentThacker sadly asking AI (which can better work with synonyms) is somehow much more reliable than raw-googling it, as one does not know the "winning" query for getting results from google that contains the answer or parts of it. on the other hand, I'm fully aware of possible AI-hallucinations (from personal experience openai fail rate is ~60% while googleai fails ~95% of times), yet, its still 1st tool in line before transition. I am aware of local movement of earth's magnetic pole, but not the position of this vector relative to sun's travel direction nor sun's vector and its behavior

@mmesser314 I would be satisfied with answer containing corrected image, depicting the true state, and hinting the overall movement of those vectors if they are significant (current earth's travelling of N/S pole would be considered as negligible from this perspective). that being said, if answer would be really worthy, containing details, images/animations, etc, I'm willing to reward it with a bounty.

@xray0 The vector simply moves in a cone around the rotation axis of the Earth. In what way is this not sufficient? The rest is just transformation between coordinate systems. I don't understand what more you are asking.

From the Wikipedia article Earth's orbit,

The magnetic pole is more complicated. First the magnetic north pole is misnamed from a physics point of view. The north pole of a magnet points north because the south pole of the Earth's magnetic field is very close to the north pole of the Earth's axis of rotation. But it is called the magnetic north pole, and I won't try to change it.
There are several images of the Earth's magnetic field in Earth's magnetic field. These might be of particular interest.


Relationship between Earth's poles. A1 and A2 are the geographic poles; B1 and B2 are the geomagnetic poles; C1 (south) and C2 (north) are the magnetic poles.

An animation shows that the magnetic poles move around surprisingly quickly.  It is too big to paste here, but you can find it at Estimated declination contours by year, 1590 to 1990
Furthermore, the magnetic north and south poles swap positions every so often. See Geomagnetic polarity during the late Cenozoic Era
